# Parsing log files and write to csv (different number of fields)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

This is a question that concerns me for a long time. I have log files that I want to convert to csv. My problem is that the empty fields have been omitted in the log files. I want to end up with a csv file containing all fields.

Now I'm parsing the log files and write them to xml because one of the nice features of Microsoft Excel is that when you open a xml file with a different number of elements, Excel shows you all elements as separate columns.

Last week I came up with the idea that this might be possible with Pandas, but I can not find a good example to get this done.

Someone a good idea how I can get this done?

**Updated**
I can't share the actual logs here. Below a fictional sample:

Sample 1:

```
First : John Last : Doe Address : Main Street Email : j_doe@notvalid.gov Sex : male State : TX City : San Antonio Country : US Phone : 210-354-4030
First : Carolyn Last : Wysong Address : 1496  Hewes Avenue Sex : female State : TX City : KEMPNER Country : US Phone : 832-600-8133 Bank_Account : 0123456789
```

regex :

```
matches = re.findall(r'(\w+) : (.*?) ', line, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Sample 2:

```
:1: John  :2: Doe :3: Main Street :4: j_doe@notvalid.gov :5: male :6: TX :7: San Antonio :8: US :9: 210-354-4030
:1: Carolyn :2: Wysong :3: 1496  Hewes Avenue :5: female :6: TX :7: KEMPNER :8: US :9: 832-600-8133 :10: 0123456789
```

regex:

```
matches = re.findall(r':(\d+): (.*?) ', line, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: Generally it depends of format of files, is possible create sample data?

Comment: `I know the desired column name.` - So is possible create for each line dict like `{'First Name':Joe, 'Last Name':Doe, 'Address':'Main Street', ...}` if regex parsing ? Or not?

Comment: If yes, then create list of dicts and pass to `DataFrame` constructor and it working nice - for missing columns are added NaNs

Comment: It's possible to do this fore every line (some of the logs are large files). Now I write them per field directly as an element to a xml file.

Comment: I do not get a memory problem with the list and/or DataFram with large files?

Comment: What is your RAM and what is size of large file?

Comment: RAM 8 GB and logs approx. 1 GB each

Comment: hmmm, it should working, but not 100% sure... Is possible see your solution with regex?

Comment: Btw, one idea - for smaller dict is possible use codes instead names like `{'First Name':Joe, 'Last Name':Doe, 'Address':'Main Street', ...}` to `{'f':Joe, 'l':Doe, 'a':'Main Street', ...}` - then dicts should be smaller. Last after create DataFrame use `df = df.rename(columns={'a':'Address', 'l':'Last Name', ...)`

Comment: My regex depends on the kind of log. But in general it's a regex with multiple groups. The desired field in the log is indicated by a name or a number

Comment: I pretty new with Pandas, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: So my idea is get the worse scenario - large file with the  longest regex and test. But if your regex is secret is hard to help with python code...

Comment: I'm going to try to make a fictional example

Comment: looking at your example lines, do they come from the same log file or different files can have different fields? if the former, how do you know a field is missing?

Comment: @filippo Logs are from the same source but unfortunately the empty fields have been omitted in the log files. If a field was empty for all log records I don't care. I want to end with all available fields.

Comment: @JohnDoe ok, what I meant is: do you have any way to see if a field is missing? like `field1;field2;;field4;;;field7` do you have a separator that tells you there was a field there that's been omitted?

Comment: @filippo No I don't. That's the point !. Please find updated samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow me to concentrate on your first example. Your regex only matches the first word of each field, but let's keep it like that for now as I'm sure you can easily fix that.

You can create a pandas `DataFrame` to store your parsed data, then for each line you run your regexp, convert it to a dictionary and load it into a pandas `Series`. Then you append it to your dataframe. Pandas is smart enough to fill missing data with `NaN`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame() 
for l in lines: 
    matches = re.findall(r'(\w+) : (.*?) ', l, re.IGNORECASE) 
    s = pd.Series(dict(matches)) 
    df = df.append(s, ignore_index=True)

>>> print(df)
  Address     City Country               Email    First    Last     Sex State         Phone
0    Main      San      US  j_doe@notvalid.gov     John     Doe    male    TX           NaN
1    1496  KEMPNER      US                 NaN  Carolyn  Wysong  female    TX  832-600-8133
```

I'm not sure the `dict` step is needed, maybe there's a pandas way to directly parse your list of tuples.

Then you can easily convert it to csv, you will retain all your columns with empty fields where appropriate.

```
df.to_csv("result.csv", index=False) 

>>> !cat result.csv                                                                                                                                                              
Address,City,Country,Email,First,Last,Sex,State,Phone
Main,San,US,j_doe@notvalid.gov,John,Doe,male,TX,
1496,KEMPNER,US,,Carolyn,Wysong,female,TX,832-600-8133
```

About big files performances, if you know all the field names in advance you can initialize the dataframe with a `columns` argument and run the parsing and csv saving one chunk at the time. IIRC there's a `mode` parameter for `to_csv` that should allow you to append to an existing file.